# How to not allow two keys to be pressed in a row in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, keypress, event-listener, keydown

Im making a snake game and need some code to not allow the same key to be pressed in a row. So for example if 'w' is pressed, it wont be able to be pressed again until another key is pressed.
Anyone now the simplest way to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: You can't prevent the user from pressing a key, you can only control how your program reacts to a key press. That said, I'm not sure this requires special handling in Snake, as the code for handling an arrow key press could easily be idempotent.

Answer (score 1):

When you receive the key press event save the last pressed key and check if the new one is the same then just return from the function.